# Pass a global javascript array value into a HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just wondering if it's possible to pass a global javascript array value into a html tag, specifically inside a img (title) tag?

Basically want to know if I can do this:

```
<img src="_info.gif" height="26" width="37" title=myArray[5]/>
```

If so, how and if not, can people possibly provide other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: why?.. what are you trying to do?

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what this would achieve..

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. I suggest that you set the title property using javascript. In order to do it you need to:

1) Add JavaScript hook to the  element. For example css class or id
2) get the element via the hook and sets its title

Example:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").title = myArray[5];

<img id="myImage" src="_info.gif" height="26" width="37"/>
```

You might as well use some kind of JavaScript library, for example jQuery or Prototype

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
<img id="image-1" src="_info.gif" height="26" width="37" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.getElementById('image-1');
image.setAttribute('title', myArray[5]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could also do:

```
<img src="_info.gif" height="26" width="37" onload="this.title = myArray[5];" />
```