# Jquery click event not working in separate js file

Tags: jquery

I was had this code before, it was working fine,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tButton").click(function(e) {
       var id = this.value;
       codeResult(id);
    });
});
```

But when I move this method to separate file I had write this

```
    $("#tButton").click(function(e) {
       var id = this.value;
       codeResult(id);
    });
```

or

```
    $("#tButton").on('click', function(e) {
       var id = this.value;
       codeResult(id);
    });
```

Both are not working, and I don't want to use `document.ready` in my .js file, what's wrong?

**UPDATE:** Wow people votes down just for my requirement, reason was too long that is why I didn't specified but here I am specifying why I don't want to use `document.ready` in .js file is

I have **jquery tab** in that multiple pages are opened now two pages have common this one .js file and more importantly first page have not this **tButton** link, so at the first time I load page in tab it will execute `document.ready` but **tButton** is not page in page so it will not bind, but now in second tab second page load but **at this time this js will not execute document.ready again**, this is the main problem so it will not bind **tButton** click event because it was previously loaded. That's why i dont want to use `document.ready`.

Hope now you will understand my complex situation.

Comment: Why do you not wish to use .ready? otherwise the dom would not be present to be able to find the id you're looking for...

Comment: Make sure you load the script file correctly

Comment: check this topic, maybe can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965409/move-document-ready-function-to-a-separate-javascript-fucntion

Comment: Two options: **(1)** Implement this function within a `$(document).ready(function () { ... });` block or **(2)** link to the script file at the end of the DOM just before body `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script></body></html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wanna use `document.ready`, then you need to call your JS file at the end, before the `body`.

```
    <!-- End of the body -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
```

Else, you need to enclose them with `$(document).ready();`. I still don't see a reason why you can't use it. Else, you can also do it in an other way:

```
window.onload = function () {
  // All the contents //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you still need to use `document.ready` in your external file.   The format of the function doesn't change because the script is external.

Try putting the `document.ready` back in...  I'm sure that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tButton").click(function(e) {
       var id = this.value;
       codeResult(id);
    });
});
```

in separated file must work